# Entity Framework получение связанных сущностей при отношении "многие ко многим"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, связи, многие-ко-многим, таблицы

Есть программа, которая должна реализовывать хранение двигателей и поиск нужного двигателя по нескольким физическим параметрам, например вес и мощность. Проблема в том, что параметров должно быть не фиксированное количество...

EntityFramework позволяет создавать отношения между сущностями вида "один ко многим", что должно решить проблему реализации. Я написал код, который подбирает нужные свойства

```
public enum QuantityType
{
    Height, Width, Weight, Power
}

public class Quantity
{
    public Quantity() { }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public QuantityType Type { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Engine
{
    public Engine() { }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Quantity> CurrentQuantities { get; set; }
}


public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("name=MyContext")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Подключение к базе данных...");
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //К двигателю много свойств
        modelBuilder.Entity<Engine>().HasMany(e => e.CurrentQuantities).WithOptional().Map(map=>map.MapKey("EngineId"));
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Engine> Engines { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static MyContext db = new MyContext();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Очистка
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.Engines");
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.Quantities");

        //Добавление данных
        var GoodQuantity = new List<Quantity>() { new Quantity() { Type = QuantityType.Power, Value = 80 } };
        var BadQuantity = new List<Quantity>() { new Quantity() { Type = QuantityType.Power, Value = 120 } };
        var AnotherQuantity = new List<Quantity>() { new Quantity() { Type = QuantityType.Power, Value = 150 } };

        Engine gx160 = new Engine() { Name = "GX160", Price = 10000,CurrentQuantities=GoodQuantity };
        Engine gx120 = new Engine() { Name = "GX120", Price = 8000, CurrentQuantities = BadQuantity };
        Engine gx200 = new Engine() { Name = "GX200", Price = 15000, CurrentQuantities = AnotherQuantity };

        db.Engines.Add(gx120);
        db.Engines.Add(gx160);
        db.Engines.Add(gx200);
        db.SaveChanges();

        /*
        Console.WriteLine("Двигатели создаются и нормально добавляются");
        foreach(var q in gx120.CurrentQuantities) Console.WriteLine(q.Type + ": " + q.Value);
        foreach (var q in gx120.CurrentQuantities) Console.WriteLine(q.Type + ": " + q.Value);
        foreach (var q in gx120.CurrentQuantities) Console.WriteLine(q.Type + ": " + q.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Как видно, их свойства тоже подцепились...");
        */

        //Поиск нужного свойства
        var RequaredQuantities = db.Set<Quantity>().Where(q => q.Type == QuantityType.Power && q.Value == 80);
        foreach(var item in RequaredQuantities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Type+": "+item.Value);
        }

        //А вот на самих двигателях я застрял...
        var RequaredEngines = ...

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Я застрял на моменте, когда имея список нужных свойств потребовалось найти сами двигатели.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Связь в базе данных по ключу создается, но техзадание не позволяет мне изменить реализацию класса Quantity, чтобы добавить свойство для доступа по связи. Как я могу получить доступ к колонке EngineId без изменения класса?

Comment: А где у вас здесь "многие ко многим"? Я пока вижу только "один-ко-многим": `Engine` 1---* `Quantity`. И где у вас `DbSet<Quantity>`? Забыли?

Comment: Надо добавить навигационные свойства в класс `Quantity
`. `public  int EngineId {get;set;}` и `public virtual Engine Engine{get;set;}`

Comment: @Bulson Действительно, связь должна быть один ко многим. Обновил код, работающий с modelBuilder

modelBuilder.Entity<Engine>().HasMany(e => e.CurrentQuantities).WithOptional().Map(map=>map.MapKey("EngineId"));

Comment: @Bulson Техзадание не позволяет изменять реализацию класса, есть ли альтернативные пути решения проблемы?

Comment: Если модель бизнес-логики нельзя изменять, то надо вводить класс сущности, которая используется в работе с БД, и мапер, который из сущности хранения создает класс модели. Как-то так.

Comment: Если у вас техзадание не позволяет менять классы доменной сущности, то вам надо задуматься о создании отдельного слоя работы с базой данных а также о том, как будете маппить домен на DAL и наоборот